# Did any country with occupied territories hold a national referendum?

Tags: referendum, territory

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupied_territories_of_Georgia), Georgia has a significant part of its country occupied by Russia:

> [...] territories occupied by Russia after the Russo-Georgian War in
>   2008. They consist of the regions of Abkhazia and the former South Ossetian Autonomous Oblast of Soviet Georgia

According to [this article](http://www.tabula.ge/en/story/110649-president-the-referendum-over-marriage-definition-wont-take-the-place), Georgia's President, Giorgi Margvelashvili said that a referendum cannot be held because the country has occupied territories:

> we should take into account the law on a referendum. It says that
>   referendum must be held on the entire territory of the country. I, as
>   the guarantee of country’s unity and national independence, am obliged
>   to defend country’s sovereignty in the first place. In the times when
>   20% of our territories is occupied and when Russia has recognized
>   occupied territories as independent states, it would give the occupant
>   more legal argumentations.

**Question:** is there any country that held referendum(s) in spite of having occupied or disputed territories that prevented it from including all its citizens within the referendum?

Comment: Maybe, but what is the relevance? If Georgia has a law requiring a referendum to be held in the whole country and country X doesn’t have such a law, then an incomplete referendum is legal in country X but not in Georgia. Of course, Georgia could repeal its law if it wanted to.

Comment: @chirlu - From the article, I understand that the main objection to having a referendum in all the country territory except the occupied parts is not providing an extra argument for Russia. Something like: if you organize a national referendum that does not include a part of your territory, you are not seeing those parts as your own.

Comment: You might have to define terms a bit carefully to get the answer you're actually interested in. For example, the Republic of Ireland's constitution defined its national territory as the the whole island of Ireland from 1937 until 1998, and they had at least a dozen referendums in that time which might count. Meanwhile citizenship and ability to vote was also complicated.

Comment: Additionally to @origimbo comment, the Republic of China (aka Taiwan) has held several referendum while still claiming to be the legitimate government of all China (I do not know if there has been any referendum in the PRC, but the situation would be the same).

Comment: @Alexei, your question mixes the voting right for *citizens* and the country's inability to establish the *polling stations* on occupied territories. If you extend the question to "national referendums *or* nation-wide elections" (which make a perfect sense) then the answer would be, definitely yes. Many countries let its citizens who reside on occupied territories to come to the controlled areas and vote there. Example: [Ukrainian presidential election, 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_presidential_election,_2014)

Comment: @bytebuster - yes, I meant national level referendum. My curiosity stems in the apparently contradiction implied by Georgia's President: national referendums that are not hold on the whole territory somehow implies not recognizing the occupied parts. This should happen in all countries who are willing to hold national referendums and also have occupied territories.

Comment: @Alexei: That's kind of the point. In the Irish and Taiwanese cases, the government had a theoretical claim to additional territories, but accepted that as a practical matter it was not going to control them in the foreseeable future. The Georgian territories have been occupied by Russia for less than 10 years; it is very much a live issue and the Georgian government has not given up hope of getting them back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Examples taken from comments*

The Republic of Ireland had claimed the whole island of Ireland, it was therefore in dispute with the UK, which controlled the North of Ireland. There were several referenda in Ireland, which did not include voters in the North.

The Republic of China claims the full territory of Mainland China, and therefore considers all people in China to be citizens. There have been referendums in the Republic of China, which did not include voters on the mainland, as it is under the administration of the PRC.